# How to get the last hidden item in the scroll from a ListView ?

Tags: android, listview

I would like to ask if it is possible to know the last viewitem which is hidden in scroll process?

Example:

We have a listview with 100 items rows. On the screen are visible 10 items rows. When I scroll down I would like to know what is the last hidden item row on the top. Is it to be taken such information?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) on your `ListView` and then implement [`onScroll(android.widget.AbsListView, int, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) .

`onScroll` gives you the first item visible. You just have to save it and compare for later calls.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @AurelGeorgiev then can you consider accepting this answer? thanks :)